# How to add status as dropdown list in UI form in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, ui-form

I have created a Ui form in magento 2. How do i kept status as dropdown list in Ui form ?
It should look in below format.
Status-1)Enabled
       2)Disabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code, it will show toggle for yes/no values

```
<field name="is_active" sortOrder="10" formElement="checkbox">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">homeslider</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <dataType>boolean</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Status</label>
        <dataScope>status</dataScope>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <checkbox>
            <settings>
                <valueMap>
                    <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                    <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
                </valueMap>
                <prefer>toggle</prefer>
            </settings>
        </checkbox>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

change field name as per your form

**Update:** For dropdown use below code

```
<field name="status" formElement="select">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">homeslider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <dataType>text</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Status</label>
        <dataScope>status</dataScope>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <select>
            <settings>
                <options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno"/>
            </settings>
        </select>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

**Update:** to change value from Yes/No to Enable/Disable Change

```
<options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno"/>
```

To

```
<options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Enabledisable"/>
```

Comment: Yes,It can work . But i need it as dropdown list which consists two options  , enabled and disabled

Comment: You mistakenly understand. I need dropdown list not like the above one. Both of your codes shows same output what i get before

Comment: See my updated question in this post

Comment: It just shows as yes or no format

Comment: How can we add this dropdown is grid also?

Answer (score 0):

Go for this option

```
<field name="active">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Active</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">active</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">general</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <!--<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>-->
                    <!--</item>-->
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```